# Wpf controls overlay?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dockpanel

I have Dockpanel on which there are two buttons (left and right sides) and a scrollviewer at the bottom. Is it possible to hide the left and right sides of this scrollviewer UNDER this buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `Grid` instead of a `DockPanel`, either use the alignments or create columns and adjust the `ColumnSpan`, example of the latter:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- Order matters, earlier controls are at the bottom unless you use Panel.ZIndex --> 
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/> 
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Left"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

*(DockPanel is quite a poor control which can easily be replaced with a Grid in about every case)*

Comment: hmmm.. thank you very much H.B. it sounds very good. i ll try to do it in my project.